# PG Promise error when select then insert the data

Tags: node.js, promise, pg-promise

i got error on my pg-promise like this:
[image]

this is my snippet code:

```
// create sample payload
let samplePayload = [];
for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
    samplePayload.push({
        id: uuidv1(),
    });
}

return db.task((t) => {

    samplePayload.map( sp => {
        // i want check if the id is exist on db
        let sql = `select * from sf_data where id = '${sp.id}'`;
        console.log(sql)
        const sampleBatch = t.any(sql).then(th => {
            // i want insert it if data not exists
            console.log(th);
        });
    })
    
});
```

i want to check if the list of data is exist in DF. If not exists, need to insert the data.

i try to fix my old code and change into this

```
const sfdata = await t.any('SELECT * FROM sf_data');

     const queries = sfdata.map((sp) => {
         return t.oneOrNone('select * from sf_data where id = ${id}', sp).then(result => {
             console.log(result)
            if(result){
                t.tx(async t2 => {
                    return t2.none("insert into test_sf values ($1, $2, $3)", [uuidv1(), result.id, result.sfid]);
                })
            }
         });
     });
     return t.batch(queries);
```

but it return error:

> (node:6547) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Client was closed and is not queryable
> at /Users/dsa/Telkom/dtp-dsa-middleware-sf/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:570:27
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)

any clue about this?

Comment: Now you added more invalid code, after you were given the answer? And you are doing the same mistakes all over, creating loose promise with `t.tx()` call. It's supposed to be `return t.tx()`. And why create a transaction for one query anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `return` in a few places, and your code creates a bunch of loose promises - queries that are trying to execute outside the connection, hence the error.

Here's correct code:

```js
return db.task(t => {
    const queries = samplePayload.map(sp => {
        return t.any('select * from sf_data where id = ${id}', sp);
    })
    return t.batch(queries);
});
```

Better yet, this can be done with one query:

```js
const ids = samplePayload.map(sp => sp.id);
return db.any('select * from sf_data where id in ($1)', [ids]);
```